# Plone 'member folders' option dont work

Tags: plone, directory, member, zope

I've enabled 'member folders' in plone administration panel. Then I've created a context menu link in the ZMI (with url: `string:${portal/portal_membership/getHomeUrl}`) to make these folders easy available.

I've noticed, that `.getHomeUrl()` always returns None, and link looks like: `127.0.0.1:80/web/None`.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: is the folder for your current user exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you normally enable that option in the Security tab of your Plone control panel:

[image: Security settings control panel]

If you set the option there, it'll also add a 'My Folder' action automatically that uses the `.getHomeUrl()` method.

`.getHomeUrl()` only returns a URL if the folder already exists. In your case it appears the folder is not yet created for the current member. The folder is first created when a member logs in but does not have their own folder yet. Logging out then in again should remedy this.

If you accidentally removed the `Members` folder from your Plone setup, you'll need to recreate it. Per-user folder creation would otherwise fail. If it is missing, simply create a new folder with the id `Members` in the root of your site.